# Prepopulate data using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to be able to use some more complex save logic before persisting in spring data.

I have this JpaRepository :

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
    @Query("from com.package.MyClass as myClass where myClass.parent is null");
    MyClass getRootMyClass();
    ...
}
```

and this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table("MY_CLASS")
public class MyClass {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("parent_id")
    MyClass parent;
}
```

I'd like to be able to do a check for null for the parent attribute and thn set the root myClass in the repository. For example, something like this:

```
if(myClass.getParent() == null) {
    myClass.setParent(getRootMyClass());  
}
```

I can't do it using the `@PrePersist` hook in the entity as it isn't aware of the repository. I can't do it in the repository because it is an interface-not a class. Where is the best place to put this?

Comment: do you mean, u want to check `if (parent!=null)` before you save an object in ur repo

Comment: what do you meant by "set the root myClass" . After doing getRootMyClass() you are saving the return value by setting parent attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK8, you can add the folowing method to `MyClassRepository`:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {

    @Query("from com.package.MyClass as myClass where myClass.parent is null")
    MyClass getRootMyClass();

    default void checkSave(MyClass myClass) {
        if (myClass.getParent() == null) {
            myClass.setParent(getRootMyClass());
        }
        save(myClass);
    }
}
```

Then, you should call checkSave() instead of save()

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Hibernate's `PreInsertEventListener`, you can register such an interceptor for every `prePersist` operation for Hibernate;

```
@Component
public class MyEventListener implements PreInsertEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MyClassRepository myClassRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent preInsertEvent) {
        if (MyClass.class.equals(preInsertEvent.getEntity().getClass())) {
            MyClass entity = (MyClass) preInsertEvent.getEntity();
            if(myClass.getParent() == null) {
                myClass.setParent(myClassRepository.getRootMyClass());  
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The idea behind this approach is that, all persist events in Hibernate will be intercepted, if there is some cascading insert for example, this will still trigger. Therefore this solution covers all possible persistence of `MyClass`, if this is too much for your requirement, other simpler solutions are preferable.